# Are Those Interrupts Normal?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, realtek, soundcard

Output from `cat /proc/interrupts`:

```
     CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:         13          0          0          0   IO-APIC   2-edge      timer
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC   8-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   9-fasteoi   acpi
 16:         29          0          0          0   IO-APIC  16-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 17:        606        839          0          0   IO-APIC  17-fasteoi   snd_hda_intel:card1
 19:         33         15        874        149   IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   rtl_pci
 23:         33          0          0          0   IO-APIC  23-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 25:      11571          0          0    1569414   PCI-MSI 327680-edge      xhci_hcd
 26:      15722          0      29559          0   PCI-MSI 512000-edge      ahci[0000:00:1f.2]
 27:         70     185068          0          0   PCI-MSI 409600-edge      eno1
 28:         16          0          0          0   PCI-MSI 360448-edge      mei_me
 29:       1205          0          0     464780   PCI-MSI 524288-edge      nvidia
 30:        762        752          0          0   PCI-MSI 442368-edge      snd_hda_intel:card0
NMI:         30         30         30         33   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    1157388    1147202    1137667     906722   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:         30         30         30         33   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          3          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:     189859     148439     138301      87188   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:     246755     273236     249782     261534   Function call interrupts
TLB:     241739     270665     247120     258759   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
DFR:          0          0          0          0   Deferred Error APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         15         15         15         15   Machine check polls
ERR:          4
MIS:          0
PIN:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt notification event
PIW:          0          0          0          0   Posted-interrupt wakeup event
```

My Audio and Video Lags some Time on every Linux Distro

```
My Mobo Gigabyte H97-D3H CF
CPU: I5.4590
Graphics Card: GTX 1060
Audio: Realtek ALC 1150
BIOS Version Ami F7
```

Medium /dev/sda: 2,7 TiB, 3000592982016 Bytes, 5860533168 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 4096 Bytes / 4096 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 1A1A7C2F-ADEE-4C42-88D7-3643256B797B

Gerät           Start       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 5827100671 5826050048  2,7T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  5827100672 5860532223   33431552   16G Linux Swap

Medium /dev/sdb: 7,3 GiB, 7855931392 Bytes, 15343616 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: dos
Medienkennung: 0x15e2543d

Gerät      Boot Start    Ende Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/sdb1  *        0 3035519  3035520  1,5G  0 Leer
/dev/sdb2       14432   19295     4864  2,4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
@heynnema
output from sudo fdisk -i

Comment: @George Thx for Helping dont now how to format this

Comment: It's all right with a little practice we all get it at last, still learning myself :)

Comment: @George have you idea for my Sound  Interrupt Problem ??

Comment: How much RAM and swap? SSD or HDD? Lets see `sudo fdisk -l`. Do you have `intel-microcode` installed?

Comment: @heynnema 16GB DD3 and yes i have microcode installed

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that you should look at, here is an except:

> Hardware interrupts are used by devices to communicate that they require attention from the operating system. Some common examples are a hard disk signalling that is has read a series of data blocks, or that a network device has processed a buffer containing network packets. Interrupts are also used for asynchronous events, such as the arrival of new data from an external network. Hardware interrupts are delivered directly to the CPU using a small network of interrupt management and routing devices. This chapter describes the different types of interrupt and how they are processed by the hardware and by the operating system. It also describes how the MRG Realtime kernel differs from the standard kernel in handling the types of interrupt.
>
> A standard system receives many millions of interrupts over the course of its operation, including a semi-regular "timer" interrupt that periodically performs maintainance and system scheduling decisions. It may also receive special kinds of interrupts, such as NMI (Non-Maskable Interrupts) and SMI (System Management Interrupts).
>
> Hardware interrupts are referenced by an interrupt number. These numbers are mapped back to the piece of hardware that created the interrupt. This enables the system to monitor which device created the interrupt and when it occured.
> In most computer systems, interrupts are handled as quickly as possible. When an interrupt is received, any current activity is stopped and an interrupt handler is executed. The handler will preempt any other running programs and system activities, which can slow the entire system down, and create latencies. MRG Realtime modifies the way interrupts are handled in order to improve performance, and decrease latency.

From that article the **numbers** beside these interrupts are an indication of the number of it occurring and the bigger the number the higher the **latency**. I have similar interrupt statistics to yours. It has not affected my system negatively as from that article the system is designed to handle them. And it's used to check the state of the components or parts of a system.

Source:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Hardware_interrupts.html